I want to create a timer for a game that I can reset. If I lift the state of the timer to the parent, the game becomes unresponsive
I am currently building a timer component to time how long players take to finish a game from the moment the website loads. If I lift the state of the timer to the parent component, the entire app re-renders every second, rendering my game unresponsive. However I wish to be able to reset the timer from my parent component.
I have moved the state to it's own component which means that my app isn't constantly re-rendering, however I am struggling with allowing my parent component reset the timer in my child timer component.
Here is my Timer component - resetTime and setResetTime are a state in the parent component
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Timer({
    characters,
    guessed,
    resetTime,
    setResetTime,
}) {
    const initialTime = 0;

    const [runningTime, setRunningTime] = useState(initialTime);

    if (resetTime === true) {
        setRunningTime(initialTime);
        setResetTime(false);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const key = setInterval(() => {
            if (guessed.length < characters.length) {
                setRunningTime((runningTime) => runningTime + 1);
            } else {
                clearInterval(key);
            }
        }, 1000);

        return () => {
            clearInterval(key);
        };
    }, [characters.length, guessed.length]);

    return <h4>{`${runningTime}`}</h4>;
}


And in my parent component I have a button that uses the resetGame() function onClick
    function resetGame() {
        handleClose();
        setGuess(initialGuess);
        setGuessed(initialGuessed);
        setResetTime(true);
    }
<button onClick={resetGame}>Reset Game</button>

This works to reset the timer, however it pops lots of errors in the console about too many re-renders whenever I click it. Further if I click on the reset timer button during the one second interval, it says that I cannot re-render the parent component while a child component is re-rendering, making my button occasionally unresponsive.

The issue with the Timer implementation is that it enqueues state updates as unintentional side-effects directly in the function component body. This logic should be moved into and applied in a useEffect hook.
Additionally, the setInterval callback closes over the current characters.length and guessed.length values when the interval is started, so the internal check is pointless since those values will never change during the lifetime of the interval callback. It can be removed.
An additional change I'd suggest would be to toggle the resetTime state back to false in the parent component so it doesn't need to be passed around because it's an implementation detail.
Example:
function resetGame() {
  handleClose();
  setGuess(initialGuess);
  setGuessed(initialGuessed);
  setResetTime(true);
  // place callback at end of Javescript event queue to allow
  // React to process the above state updates and rerender
  // at least once
  setTimeout(setResetTime, 0, false);
}

...

<Timer characters={characters} guessed={guessed} resetTime={resetTime} />

const initialTime = 0;

function Timer({ characters, guessed, resetTime }) {
  const [runningTime, setRunningTime] = useState(initialTime);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (resetTime) {
      setRunningTime(initialTime);
    }
  }, [resetTime]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const key = setInterval(() => {
      setRunningTime((runningTime) => runningTime + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(key);
    };
  }, [characters.length, guessed.length]);

  return <h4>{runningTime}</h4>;
}

I think you have a good use case for the useImperativeHandle handle where the Timer component defines a resetTime function and exposes it out via a React ref. This way the logic is coupled to the component that uses it instead of relying on all parent components to implement it.
Example:
const timerRef = useRef();

...

function resetGame() {
  handleClose();
  setGuess(initialGuess);
  setGuessed(initialGuessed);
  timerRef.current.resetTime();
}

...

<Timer ref={timerRef} characters={characters} guessed={guessed} />

import {
  forwardRef,
  useEffect,
  useState,
  useImperativeHandle,
} from "react";

const initialTime = 0;

const Timer = forwardRef(({ characters, guessed }, ref) => {
  const [runningTime, setRunningTime] = useState(initialTime);

  useImperativeHandle(
    ref,
    () => ({
      resetTime: () => setRunningTime(initialTime),
    }),
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    const key = setInterval(() => {
      setRunningTime((runningTime) => runningTime + 1);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(key);
    };
  }, [characters.length, guessed.length]);

  return <h4>{runningTime}</h4>;
});

